# Does Java have an equiavalent to boost's or Qt's signals?

Tags: java

The features mentioned in title serve a simple purpose: allow an user to bind some event listeners to an object which will dispatch all event listeners when event occurs.

This simple concept can, of course, achieved like this:

```
public class EventEmitter extends ArrayList<Runnable>;
```

But I would prefer a smarter emitter - ideally one that allows arguments to be passed to the callback. Runnable does not have any arguments of course. Lambda expressions do have parameters on the other side.

Smart emitters allow you to define specific callback parameters:

```
EventEmitter<String, Boolean> emitter = new EventEmitter();
```

My question whether this thing is part of java library or if I have to implement it myself. On google, I only found some `java.awt.AWTEvent` but that is not event dispatcher.

My preferred pseudo code:

```
// Requires lambdas with (File, int) signature
public final EventEmitter<File, int> downloadCompleteEvent;
```

And new events added as:

```
downloaderClass.downloadCompleteEvent
   .addListener(
       (File file, int downloadTime)->System.out.println("Downloaded "+file.getAbsolutePath()+" in "+downloadTime+" seconds.")
   );
```

And dispatch events as:

```
this.downloadCompleteEvent.dispatch(downloadedFile, elapsedTime);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure Java, you can use a `CompletableFuture` which represents a state or a work currently in action. On a completable future, you can add one or more listeners which will be invoked with result.

by example:

```
public CompletableFuture<DownloadResult> download() {
    // computing a result async
    CompletableFuture<DownloadResult> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(/* your process*/);
    return future;
}

future.thenAccept( (DownloadResult) r -> { ... } ); 
// will be called when process is done
```

Also, you can be interested by EventBus into Guava library: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained

Or by RXJava library: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/How-To-Use-RxJava

Comment: I assume `CompletableFuture` is for one use only.

Comment: You can add multiple listeners/callbacks on one completable future, you can also chain processes, but you need to have a new one future for each execution, yes

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try to make use of this information. If you come to think of anything else, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Some libraries may have a class that can be extended to add this functionality, but it is not a native java idiom. If you want this functionality you need to track and notify event listeners yourself via the observer pattern.

Comment: I need more info, can you add something to the answer? How does awt do it?